# Updates Labels in Swift when using popoverController

Tags: label, swift

I have a question about swift,

I made a popover controller in a UIViewController,which display a list of books
and when the user click on one of the books, the label on the viewController should be updated with the name of the selected book.

But in my case when I select a name of a book, the label does not update

here is the code :

```
// View Controller

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPopoverControllerDelegate {
    var popoverController : UIPopoverController? = nil
    @IBOutlet var bookName : UILabel
    var BookNameString : String?{
    didSet{
        configureView()
    }
    }

    func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let detail = self.BookNameString {
            if let label = bookName {
                label.text = detail
            }
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    @IBAction func Click(sender : UIButton) {
        var tableView:TableViewController = TableViewController(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        var popoverContent:UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tableView)
        self.popoverController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: popoverContent)
        self.popoverController!.delegate = self
        self.popoverController!.presentPopoverFromRect(sender.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

and here is the code of the TableViewController when a row is selected:

```
// TableViewController

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!){

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var details = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as ViewController


    var keyString = bookSectionKeys[indexPath.section]
    var bookValues = book.booksLetters[keyString]!
    var selectedBookString = bookValues[indexPath.row]
    var selectedBookValues = book.bookDictionary[selectedBookString]!

    details.BookNameString = selectedBookString


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem a few weeks ago and I want to share the solution with you :)

I solve it using protocols.

OK Here what I did in details:

1. First I created a protocol in the view that I want it to display inside the popover and I named the protocol "DismissPopoverDelegate"

   ```
   protocol DismissPopoverDelegate{
          func didSelectBook(SelectedBook:String)
   }
   ```
2. Then I declared a variable of type DismissPopoverDelegate and name it "delegate"

   ```
   var delegate: DismissPopoverDelegate?
   ```
3. Then in the didSelectRowAtIndexMethod:

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!){
   var keyString = bookSectionKeys[indexPath.section]
   var bookValues = book.booksLetters[keyString]!
   var selectedBookString = bookValues[indexPath.row]
   delegate?.didSelectBook(selectedBookString)
   }
   ```
4. After that inside the View that contains the popover (View Controller), I set the delegate of the view:

   ```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, DismissPopOverDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate{
   ```
5. Then to make the view confirm to the protocol DismissPopOverDelegate, I implement the method "didSelectBook" Inside the view:

   ```
   func didSelectBook(SelectedBook:String){
      popoverController!.dismissPopoverAnimated(true) // This is Optional
      bookName.text = SelectedBook // Make the label text equal to the selected book From the table
   }
   ```
6. Finally, I set the delegate to the tableView to View Controller

   ```
   tableView.delegate = self
   ```

That's it :)

Here is the full code of the viewController that contains the popover

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, DismissPopOverDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate{
   @IBOutlet var booksbarButton : UIBarButtonItem
   @IBOutlet var bookName : UILabel    
   var popoverController : UIPopoverController? = nil
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
   }
   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }  
   @IBAction func showTableView(sender : UIBarButtonItem) {
       var tableView:TableViewController = TableViewController(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
       tableView.delegate = self
       var popoverContent:UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tableView)
       self.popoverController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: popoverContent)
       popoverController!.delegate = self
       self.popoverController!.presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem(booksbarButton, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
   }
   func didSelectBook(SelectedBook:String){
       popoverController!.dismissPopoverAnimated(true)
       bookName.text = SelectedBook
   }
}
```